# Android How To Get The Return Value String From SQLite Cursor Query And Display It In Edittext?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-edittext

When I run the SQLite Cursor Query it fails to display the result string in the edittext.

It fails with the Logcat message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

How can I get the query result value string from the cursor and display it in the edittext?

```
public class Books extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

 private BooksData books;

 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.books);

        books = new BooksData(this);

        }

        SQLiteDatabase db1 = books.getReadableDatabase();

        SEARCH_TERM = "math";

        EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext1);

        // Get the value from TITLE when the TOPIC value is specified, ie such as "math".

        Cursor cursor_2 = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "TOPIC", "TITLE"}, "TOPIC = ?", new String[]{ ""+SEARCH_TERM+"" }, null, null, null, null);

        String TEMP_DATA = cursor_2.getString(2);

        edittext.setText(TEMP_DATA);

books.close();
cursor_2.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move to the first record in the cursor before you can pull data from it.

```
Cursor cursor_2 = db1.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"_id", "TOPIC", "TITLE"}, "TOPIC = ?", new String[]{ ""+SEARCH_TERM+"" }, null, null, null, null);

if (cursor_2 == null)
   return;

try{
   if (cursor_2.moveToFirst()) // Here we try to move to the first record
        edittext.setText(cursor_2.getString(2)); // Only assign string value if we moved to first record
}finally { 
   cursor_2.close();
}
```

Comment: dymmeh, your solution works great! Thank you for providing the answer.

Comment: dymmeh, your solution works great! Thank you for providing the answer.

Comment: @user2308699 - No problem. Make sure to mark it as the answer if you feel it was the proper solution.